# Tuple with For-Each loop

Tags: c#, wcf, foreach, tuples

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here or if something is actually wrong.

It might totally be an overlook which is why I sent it to community to take a look.

I am creating a `List` of `Tuple<T,Boolean>` on client side and returning to WCF via REST JSON.
I am getting the value perfectly fine at the server side. However, when I try to use them in a `for each` loop, the items show up as `NULL` and err out.

Interestingly, I replaced the `for each` loop with Classic `for` loop and the code works perfectly file.

Below is the code I am using. Also attaching is the image which contains details about my scenario I am putting here.

```
//This code fails
foreach (Tuple<Candidate, Boolean> cand in candidateList) //candidateList has got items perfectly in it.
{
  Candidate cd = cand.Item1; //cand comes out as NULL
    if (cd.IsShortlisted)
       InsertShortCandidates(jobPost.JobID.ToString(), cd.UserID, cd.MatchingScore.ToString());
    else
       RemoveShortCandidates(jobPost.JobID.ToString(), cd.UserID);
}

//This code runs perfectly fine
for (Int32 idx = 0; idx < candidateList.Count; idx++) // As expected candidateList has got items.
{
    Tuple<Candidate, Boolean> cand = candidateList[idx]; // Here cand has got values good to be used further. 
    Candidate cd = cand.Item1;
    if (cd.IsShortlisted)
       InsertShortCandidates(jobPost.JobID.ToString(), cd.UserID, cd.MatchingScore.ToString());
    else
       RemoveShortCandidates(jobPost.JobID.ToString(), cd.UserID);
}
```

[image: Tuples with Foreach]

Comment: What is the value of `candidateList.Where(z => z == null).Count()`?

Comment: What is the value of `candidateList.GetType()`?

Comment: candidateList.Where(z => z == null).Count() = 0

Comment: @AshutoshVyas show us more about `candidateList` is it really `Candidate` as `T` in it ?

Comment: please post "Candidate" class

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily iterate through Tuple in this way,Lets say I have a class

**Class**

```
  public class MyClass
    {


        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
```

**List of Tuple**

```
 List<Tuple<MyClass, bool>> listoftuple = new List<Tuple<MyClass, bool>>();
```

**Set List of Tuple**

```
  for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++)
        {
            MyClass cls = new MyClass();
            cls.Counter = i;
            Tuple<MyClass, bool> tuple =
                new Tuple<MyClass, bool>(cls, true);
            listoftuple.Add(tuple);

        }
```

**Get Tuple value**

```
 foreach (Tuple<MyClass, bool> item in listoftuple)
        {
            Tuple<MyClass, bool> gettuple = item;
            Console.WriteLine(gettuple.Item1.Counter);
            Console.WriteLine(gettuple.Item2);


        }
```

**Problem with your code**

The problem in your code is the first line of foreach loop

> Candidate cd = cand.Item1;

Try replace with

```
Tuple<Candidate, Boolean> cd = cand
```

Then

```
Candidate candidate = cd.Item1
```

Comment: Interesting. But does't foreach actually cast the object to proper type. Why is an additional intermediate variable required ?

Comment: This is because you are iterating through a list of class which has the class inside each list ,so you need to first get each list then fetch the class from it.In for loop case you are iterating through each list of tuple then getting each list first inside "cand " then getting the desire class from that list.